# MySQL Trigger Error: Updating the one table's field value based upon another table updates or insertions

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to update one table in MySQL based upon another table update and insertions. Scenario is like this, when someone change the status of the column in main table the child table's column field should be update for their matching ID. 
Tables look like as below:

```
po_request 
Id  po_id   status
1   E0001   Requested
2   E0002   Received
```

PO_LINE

```
Id po_id is_received 
6  E0001    0
7  E0002    0
```

Need to update the Po_line table each time when status has changed to "Received" OR directly insert the "received" in the table. I have made trigger but it's not working. Trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `t1`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `t1`
AFTER UPDATE ON po_request FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF NEW.`status` = 'Received' 
THEN 
UPDATE po_line JOIN po_request ON po_request.po_id = po_line.po_id SET is_received = '1' WHERE po_request.status = 'Received'; END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Trigger loaded into table successfully but when I update the table it throws very weird error:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'date_received' in 'field list'.

Comment: You might want to include the exact MySQL error code which your trigger is currently throwing.

Comment: Why would you do this through a trigger?  Just join to the parent to get the information you want.

Comment: I need to update po_line table's column value every time when someone change the status such as from request to received in the po_request table that's why I need to put trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to update it by avoid joining the table and match in `where` clause with the reference of `NEW` keyword. which refers to the other table `id` like :

```
UPDATE po_line 
SET po_line.is_received = '1' 
WHERE new.po_id = po_id 
AND po_request.status = 'Received';
```